# Any npm package similar to google page translator?

Tags: angular, npm, google-translate

Any npm package similar to google page translator? I have added it to my angular but I just wanted to know if there is anything similar but npm package version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLvJo.png)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate Try this

Answer (score 0):

This one uses Google translate by defaul but you can change it to Yandex.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/translate

There's antoher one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-translator